# Problemas al contar en una Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

La estructura de las tablas es la siguiente:

**child**

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD(
child_id SMALLINT,
child_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(255),
city VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT PK_CHILD PRIMARY KEY(child_id)
```

**letter**

```
CREATE TABLE LETTER(
letter_id SMALLINT,
arrival_date DATE NOT NULL,
number_toys INTEGER NOT NULL,
delivery_mode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
child_id SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_LETTER PRIMARY KEY(letter_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);
```

**wished_toy**

```
 CREATE TABLE WISHED_TOY(
 letter_id SMALLINT,
 toy_id SMALLINT,
 CONSTRAINT PK_WISHED_TOY PRIMARY KEY(letter_id, toy_id),
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (letter_id) REFERENCES LETTER(letter_id)
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (toy_id) REFERENCES TOY(toy_id)
 );
```

**toy**

```
CREATE TABLE TOY(
toy_id SMALLINT,
toy_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL NOT NULL,
toy_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_TOY PRIMARY KEY(toy_id),
);
```

Se me pide una query con los juguetes pedidos(wished_toy) al menos 3 veces en cartas recibidas (letter) a partir del año 2016.

Tengo esto,que me muestra de cada carta (letter) pedida desde 2016 cada jueguete que se ha pedido,lo que no se es como contar
los toy_id que son iguales para asi filtrar los juguetes que han sido pedido minimo 3 veces.

```
select l.letter_id,wi.toy_id 
from letter l
join wished_toy wi
on l.letter_id=wi.letter_id
where l.arrival_date >= '2016-01-01'
group by l.letter_id,wi.toy_id
order by letter_id asc
```

Me saca esto:

```
   letter_id   toy_id
       1          3
       1          4
       1          1
       2          4
```

Y así...el caso es como puedo sumar o contar los juguetes que se han pedido repetidos al menos 3 veces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La tabla wished_toy no te dará el nombre del juguete, que pareciera ser lo que te piden. Hay que joinear con `toy`. Yo lo haría como:

```
SELECT 
   toy.toy_name,
   COUNT(*) cantidad
FROM toy
JOIN wished_toy USING (toy_id)
JOIN letter l USING (letter_id)
WHERE l.arrival_date>='2016-01-01'
GROUP BY toy_name
```

Esto parte de la base que la tabla de paso `wished_toy` no tiene registros duplicados. Esto es, que una misma carta no puede pedir dos veces el mismo juguete. (Santa Claus, por favor tráeme una muñeca, un monopoly y una muñeca. WTF). Tal vez sería más defensivo hacer

```
SELECT 
   toy.toy_name,
   COUNT(DISTINCT letter_id) cantidad
FROM toy
JOIN wished_toy USING (toy_id)
JOIN letter l USING (letter_id)
WHERE l.arrival_date>='2016-01-01'
GROUP BY toy_name
```

Pero en el fondo, si una misma carta pide dos veces el mismo juguete, supongo que puede ser correcto contar el juguete dos veces y en ese caso la primera query sería la indicada.